# DayLightSavingMode issue in Android

Tags: android, datetime, sharepoint, utc, dst

I know this Questions Asked before so many time but i didn't get solution from it.

I am trying to convert Datetime to UTC-0.

I have backend as microsoft sharepoint O365.

I am adding record in sharepoint List.

I am store user timezone when it register. so now whenever user login they can see all data with dateandtime in their selected timezone which  store at time of registration.

Now my point is user registered timezone is Asia/Kolkata.

now if he login using other country device like London. then he can see all data date time in Asia/Kolkata which is selected at register time.

**For eg.** User registered  timezone at time of registration like  GMT+5:30 then if user mobile timezone is whatever they can see in GMT+5:30 DateTime

And if he add any data from app then it also store as Asia/Kolkata timezone which  Datetime not as current mobile timezone if he using Mobile in london.

how to Resolve it?

my code like below:

```
    public  String getDateAndTimeToUserFormat()
{

    String date;
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Indian Standard Time");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);


    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat(serverdateFormat, Locale.US);
   simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);

date= simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

Log.i("TAG","UserTimezone=>"+this.timeZone);
Log.i("TAG","Time zone: " + timeZone.getID());

Log.i("TAG","default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
Log.i("TAG","default time : " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Log.i("TAG","UTC:     " + date);
Log.i("TAG","Default: " + calendar.getTime());



    return date;

}
```

**Output:**
UserTimezone=>India Standard Time
 **Time zone:** GMT

**default time zone:** Africa/Casablanca

**default time :** Fri Jun 17 12:53:55 GMT+00:00 2016

**UTC:**     2016-06-17T12:53:55Z

**Default:** Fri Jun 17 12:53:55 GMT+00:00 2016

Comment: You should show what times you are getting, and which are not what you are expecting.  At a guess, if you _want_ UTC, then 1 hour's difference to London will be correct; if you _want_ "watch time" in London, then you don't want UTC: presumably you'll need to convert _from_ Indian time (to UTC) and then convert that _to_ London time.

Comment: @TripeHound actually i am trying to add record in sharepoint in that i have  UTC-0 timezone now when i am adding there its show 1 hour plus time but  i want to show same time . mean if its daylightsaving time mode then why i cant get time accurate?

Comment: @if I change setting of Timezone of sharepoint to UTC+5.30 then its show exact time which i am inserting there.but if i change it to UTC-0  then its should  be show which i am adding time.

Comment: Again, edit some concrete examples in to your question for clarity... For example, I don't know whether you are saying that the problem is that the code above is not generating correct UTC time, or that -- having generated the correct UTC time -- when you store this in Sharepoint (which isn't mentioned in the question at all!) then _Sharepoint_ is displaying it "wrong". If the latter, Sharepoint is probably displaying it in "local time" which [correctly] includes the DST offset.

Comment: @TripeHound in short I am adding UTC time then its should show same which i am adding.

Comment: @TripeHound yeah its store in LocalTime i think but how can i covert here my time to localtime

Comment: The IANA time zone for India is `Asia/Kolkata`.  You're trying to use a Windows time zone ID in Android.  See [the list of valid time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  As to your question, it is completely unclear how Sharepoint fits into the code you showed or what you're actually asking.  Therefore, I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**finally i have make code for my requirement.**

```
 public String getDateTimeToUTC() {

        String result=convertToUTCDateTime(convertToUserDateTime(this.timeZone));

    return result;

}

/**
 *
 * @param userTimeZone : is contain String Of User Selected TimeZone
 * @return Date: it contain DateTime of UserSelected TimeZone
 */


 public Date convertToUserDateTime(String userTimeZone)
{ Date parsed = null;
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(userTimeZone);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
        new SimpleDateFormat(serverdateFormat, Locale.US);
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
String date = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
try {
parsed=simpleDateFormat.parse(date);

    Log.i("TAG", "default time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    Log.i("TAG", "User Selected Timezone=>" + timeZone.getID());
    Log.i("TAG", "default Device DateTime : " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Log.i("TAG","User selected  DateTime=>"+date);


} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return parsed ;
}    /**
 * @param userZoneDateTime : is contain User Selected TimeZone Date
 * @return String : Return UTC-0 DateTime String From User Selected DateTimeZone
 */
public  String convertToUTCDateTime(Date userZoneDateTime)
{
    String result;
    TimeZone timeZone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 =
            new SimpleDateFormat(serverdateFormat, Locale.US);
    simpleDateFormat1.setTimeZone(timeZone1);


        result = simpleDateFormat1.format(userZoneDateTime);
        Log.i("TAG", "UTC Time zone: " + timeZone1.getID());
        Log.i("TAG", "UTC:     " + result);

    return result;

}
```